# Got stuck with JNI - help needed

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I developed my Java application, but suddenly got stuck with JNI. 
I try to compile and run most simple JNI application ever (just to figure out what's wrong). I have Win7 x64, JDK 7 32-bit, MinGW.
Here is my Java class with a single native method.

```
package my.pack;

public class Foo
{
    static
    {
        try
        {
            System.loadLibrary("foo");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not load native library");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.foo();
    }

    public native void foo();
}
```

I run

```
javah my.pack.Foo
```

to generate my_pack_Foo.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class my_pack_Foo */

#ifndef _Included_my_pack_Foo
#define _Included_my_pack_Foo
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     my_pack_Foo
 * Method:    foo
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_pack_Foo_foo
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Then I implement it in my_pack_Foo.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "my_pack_Foo.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_pack_Foo_foo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    puts("HELLO WORLD!");
}
```

Then I compile cpp file:

```
g++ -shared -o foo.dll my_pack_Foo.cpp -I c:/JDK/include -I c:/JDK/include/win32
```

I try to run compiled Foo.java with 32-bit JVM but get error (foo.dll is on system path):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: my.pack.Foo.foo()V
        at my.pack.Foo.foo(Native Method)
        at my.pack.Foo.main(Foo.java:20)
```

Everything seems to be right, but what's wrong?

Comment: Two things you might try are to add logging to indicate successful library load (even though in theory you will already log a failure), and to examine the library with objdump or whatever and see if the function in question is actually there, and under the expected name.  Since you are starting with C++ might you have some issue with name mangling?

Comment: What do you see in `nm --extern-only --defined-only` output for your DLL?

Answer (score 1):

When linking, use the following options

`-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -m32 -shared`

Use Dependancy Walker(http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to validate your exports before and after to see the difference.